# How can I find out/display the mailbox that a particular message is in with neomutt+notmuch?

Tags: mutt, notmuch

I am using notmuch together with neomutt. I am using the recommended setup, i.e. I can search for messages matching certain criteria with `/` and results are shown in a virtual folder directly in mutt, which is nice. I keep all of my email in different IMAP mailboxes, i.e. INBOX is - in theory - empty.

Because of this, quite often, I would like to know in which mailbox a particular message is that I found through notmuch. Is there a way to do so? Or, even better, is there a way to directly jump to the corresponding mailbox and thread from the search results?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Neomutt release [20201120](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/releases/tag/20201120) changes behaviour of `%b` index_format expando for notmuch virtual mailboxes to be more consistent with the [docs](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#index-format)

> %b Filename of the original message folder (think mailbox)

Note: When the same message is present in multiple maildirs indexed into the single notmuch database, only the last indexed maildir name is shown.

Big thanks to [Austin Ray](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/339804/austin-ray)